# Uniform convergence of the sequence of functions: $g_n(x) = \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k\ln(k)}f(kx)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. Let $(g_n)_n$ be the sequence of functions defined by
\begin{align}
g_n(x) = \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k\ln(k)}f(kx).
\end{align}
I need to prove that $(g_n)$ converges uniformally on $\mathbb{R}$.

Here is the way I thought of: Since the limit function is not given here and it may be hard to guess, I thought that the best way to prove the uniform convergence is to use Cauchy condition. That is, we begin by $\varepsilon > 0$ and seek $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |g_n(x) - g_m(x)| = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \left| \sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k\ln(k)}f(kx) \right| < \varepsilon
\end{align}
whenever $n>m>n_0$. My question is how to prove this supremum is less than $\varepsilon$.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have an absolute value above. I already thought of this inequality.

Comment: @TitoEliatron: I don't think your inequality is true

Comment: Also I don't think this question is right. Any function $f$ such that $f(n)=(-1)^n \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ would lead to a divergence at $x=1$

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen OUCH yes, you're right